# Why doesn't this loop return to the first index?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, indexing

I'm confused here, when the if is true it does not go back to the first index. I don't know why I have done it before, but I did not save in a safe place. Now I have spent a lot of time looking for the solution, can someone help me?

```
var digital = document.getElementById("placeDiv").style;

var abc = ["red","blue","green"];

for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
digital.backgroundColor=abc[i];alert(i);if(abc["green"]){i=0};
};
```

Comment: When would `if(abc["green"])` be true?

Comment: there are better ways of making infinite loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if(abc[i] === "green")
```

I don't know what you are planning to do. But your code will be in a infinite loop.

Comment: I want to remove the alert(i) and I know it's possible... I'll figure it out, since you guys kinda refreshed my memory.

Answer (score 1):

The result of this will be an infinite loop because when the loop reaches the 3rd object in the array it will start again from the 1st.
If you want an infinite loop it is cleaner to use while(true){}

```
var digital = document.getElementById("placeDiv").style;

var abc = ["red","blue","green"];

for(var i=0;i<abc.length;i++){
    digital.backgroundColor=abc[i];
    alert(i);
    if(abc[i]=="green"){
         i=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I remove the alert(i)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but maybe what you want is:

```
if (abc[i] === "green") {
```

But keep in mind that even though i gets reset to 0 when this condition is met, it immediately gets bumped up to 1 at the top of the loop. You would then be in an infinite loop with i going from 1 to 2 and then back again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to a while loop. Currently you will end up with a loop counter that will never be lower than 1 after the first execution. You are setting i to  0 but when then loop finishes it is incremented. I changed your code to a while loop with an if-then test to either increment the loop counter or set it to zero. It works fine for me now.

```
    var i=0;
    while (i<3){
            digital.backgroundColor = abc[i];
            //alert(i);
            if(abc[i] === "green"){
              i=0
            } else {
                i++;
            }
         }
```

Comment: How can the alert be removed? So far only with the alert.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your question. If you tell us a bit more about what you are trying to do with this script we may be able to help you more. If you just don't want the alert to show, you could simply delete the.    alert(i);    Line of code. Alternatively you could comment that line out.

Comment: I commented out the alert line in my above answer. The alert will not display anymore if you use that code.

Comment: Infinite polygons algorithm for games and Digital Interactive Video(DIV).

Comment: Screen pixel sync for HD display on a browser.

Comment: I changed my original answer so that the alert will not display.